# Как хранить разные типы объектов в одном массиве, коллекции

Tags: c#, наследование

Я создаю игру, и у меня есть класс игрока и других игровых объектов. Мне нужно, чтобы они находились что-то типо в одном массиве, чтобы я мог их постоянно сортировать по координате Y.

Это переменные, которые есть у каждого класса, это нужно для того, чтобы был правильный порядок отрисовки игровых объектов. Я пытался делать наследование, делать абстрактный класс, от которого всё наследовалось, но в c# я не очень силён.

Я просто слышал, что нужно сделать общего родителя, и тогда как-то можно будет хранить детей от родителя в одном месте.

```
public class Objects
{
    public int x = 10;
    public int y = 10;

}

public class Player
{
    public int x = 10;
    public int y = 10;
}

public class Tree
{
    public int x = 10;
    public int y = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Мысль правильная, нужно создать одного общего родителя и наследовать его:

```cs
public abstract class Objects
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Player : Objects { }
public class Tree : Objects { }
```

Затем создавайте нужные объекты:

```
var player = new Player
{
    X = 10,
    Y = 20
};

var tree = new Tree
{
    X = 5,
    Y = 20
};
```

И используйте их в массиве:

```cs
var array = new Objects[] { player, tree }; //<-- Обратите внимание, что явно указан тип массива
```

Так же можно использовать и List:

```cs
var list = new List<Objects> { player, tree };
```

Теперь, обращаясь к любому элементу в `array`, вы получите доступ к нужным свойствам X и Y:

```
if (array[0].Y == array[1].Y)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Works!");
}
```

Обратите внимание, что я заменил из вашего примера публичные поля на публичные свойства, публичные поля лучше не использовать.

UPD 1:
Чтобы получить обратно нужный тип из `Objects` нужно использовать [Cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions):

```cs
//вариант 1
var player = (Player)array[0];
var tree = (Tree)array[1];

//вариант 2
var player = array[0] as Player; //(!)тут player может стать null, если в массиве на 0 индексе будет не тип Player, а другой.

//вариант 3
if (array[0] is Player player) //выполняет вариант 2, но еще и проверяет на null, если там null - if не выполняется
{
    player.X = 10;
}
```

UPD 2:
Так же можно использовать интерфейсы:

```
public interface IObjects
{
    int X { get; set; } //<-- все свойства интерфейса изначально public
    int Y { get; set; }
}

public class Player : IObjects
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}

public class Tree : IObjects
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

И в таком случае вы тоже можете создавать массив из первого примера и работать с ним точно так же:

```
var array = new IObjects[] { player, tree }; //<-- Обратите внимание, что явно указан тип массива
```

Comment: Стоит наверно немного расширить ответ, добавив как получить конкретный тип из обобщенного, а также наверно стоит про интерфейсы упомянуть, а то человек будет думать, что это единственный способ.

Comment: Ну, тоже верно. Спасибо за уточнение, расширю ответ

Comment: Все работает, но не хотелось бы вводить каждую переменную при создании объекта, ведь у меня их будет очень много, можно ли чтобы все переменные брались из класса Player и Tree и не приходилось их назначать при инициализации объекта? Если просто сделать List, оставив дефолтные переменные класса Player и Tree, то он просто берёт их из родительского класса, можно ли как-то обойтись без приведения типом?

Comment: Смотря на чем делаете игру, за Unity я не знаю, может там и можно как-то автоматически всё сделать. На ум приходит только отдельный сервис в DI и фабрика для объектов, которая сама пишет в этот сервис новые объекты.